# Problem query get to api rest with authorization bearer

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, bearer-token

I need to make a query by getting to an api rest with authorization bearer, the problem is that the vb.net code returns an error in the GetResponse.

---

**ERRORS:**

The connection is terminated: Unexpected shipping error.

IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The interruption of an existing connection has been forced by the remote host.

SocketException: The interruption of an existing connection has been forced by the remote host**

---

I'm not sure the code is correct since I have not found very good examples on the internet ...

I would appreciate the help of someone who understands a bit more than me about the topic

Thanks for all!

```
    Dim s As HttpWebRequest
    Dim r As HttpWebResponse
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    s = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.xxxx.net/api/v1/PrivilegedCustomers/byIdentity/D/04400012680")
    s.Method = "GET"
    s.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & Token())
    's.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


    r = DirectCast(s.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream())

    Dim json_api As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(json_api)
```

Comment: Add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` right after the `Dim` statements, see whether the error is resolved or it becomes something else.

Comment: the problem persists....

Comment: Try addiing this a certificate validation (right after you've set the SecurityProtocol) `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, Cert, Chain, sslErrors) Return True End Function` (in 3 lines of code). You should find the REST Api requirements in its documentation. Also, add a CookieContainer, just in case: `s.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()`. If in `(...) "Bearer " & Token())`, `Token()` is a function, assign the result to a local variable and inspect its content.